# Using AutoFilter in Excel Macro to exclude criteria from application.inputbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am unable to use application.inputbox stored as variable to exclude criteria using autofilter.  I have tried several methods, but it seeems to ignore my variable I am passing through to the autofilter critera.

This is the code I am using.  I tried it without the filtervalue variable, and instead passted myvalue directly into the autofilter in the Criteria1 portion, but that didnt work.  I then tried to create a new variable Filtervalue to pass it as one string, that doesnt work.   Not sure if I need to use Advanced autofilter, or if there is some issue somewhere in this that is causing the inputbox data not to pass through as a variable

```
Sub Inputbox()
Sheets("exceptions").Select
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Dim myValue As Variant
Dim FilterValue As Variant

myValue = Application.Inputbox("Cycle")
FilterValue = "<>" 'MyValue'

myRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=FilterValue, _
        Operator:=xlAnd
        
        

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `FilterValue = "<>" & MyValue`?

Comment: Awesome!. that was it.  I guess I was not combining the <> and Myvalue without the &